# tracing javascript file while doing special activities on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, function, methods, trace

I have a button in a web page and I know that when I clicked on the button a series of variables are set based on the web page status and #textbox values and other activities that I took on #webpage. And finally these collections of variables are send to another servers.
All these functions are defined throughout the .js files which are attached in the html file.
I want to trace when I fill the #textbox and click on the button and discover how the variables are set and changed. Is there any solution for that? 
And how can I send these variables myself to the server without letting the #.js do that?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by `how the variables are set`? Did you mean when it is set or did you mean to get a callback when modified or did you mean who is the modifier? What have you tried? Help us to help you by showing some code. Perhaps a little fiddle will help a lot.

Comment: If I understand you right, there is a form on a website that you can fill out. When the form is submitted its sent to the server. You want to bypass filling out the form and send the information directly to the server. If I were you, I'd try to trace to variables to something like an ajax request where they'd get sent to the server.

Comment: exactly i want to do some similar scenarios. i have trace the ajax request and i cheat thexhr parameters in firefox debug and console but i don't know how to set them.